# How to scaffold Razor page without a datacontext?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

When I execute the following line to scaffold a razor page:

`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m EncryptTextModel -udl -outDir Pages\EncryptTextModel --referenceScriptLibraries`

I get this output:

`Building project ...
Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
Running the generator 'razorpage'...
Please provide a valid dataContext
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:06.71`

This page doesn't persist data to a database so it doesn't need a dataContext - it simply encrypts text. **How do I get ASP.NET to scaffold this page without a datacontext?**

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017. I'm using this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model) as my guide.

Comment: You can use 'dotnet new page -n EncryptTextModel' to create a new blank page.